# Writing wysiwyg content to Word Document

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, ms-office

I am using CKeditor to get some data from user and i d like to save whatever user types on this very html editor to Word Document without losing the look and feel.

I have done lot of searching but wansnt able to find any resources actually.

Some of which are : 
[How can a Word document be created in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c)

[Problem writing HTML content to Word document in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801255/problem-writing-html-content-to-word-document-in-asp-net)

so on.

Not sure why there is no clear direction on this.

Any pointers? libraries you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Open XML sdk` to create word documents programatically without installing word on the server. And you can convert simple html to word document using [Html to Openxml](http://html2openxml.codeplex.com/). Alternatively you can insert the html file into word document as an alt chunk without losing the formatting (unless you using external css). An example code for it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91894/HTML-as-a-Source-for-a-DOCX-File) and [this one](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/03/28/importing-html-that-contains-numbering-using-altchunk.aspx).